# How to search all repo in Github while in another repo?

Tags: github

I think Github changed the search bar functionality.
Now when I type anything into the search bar, it defaults to searching **within** the repo that I'm browsing.

I want to search the entire Github in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately your request doesn't seems to be possible**<sup>[1]</sup> without any extension or script that will change GitHub's functionality.

- It's not new at all, I don't remember how long it's that way - but not from lately.
- The options you have are:

  - Search in the repo and then click the "view all results.." to search entire GitHub.

    > N code results in X/Y or view [all results on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=my%20search%20phrase)
  - Go to the [homepage](https://github.com/) or navigate to the [search page](https://github.com/search).
  - Write an extension/script that will alter this behavior for you.

You can read more about this on this article:

- [About searching on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-searching-on-github/)

<sup>[1]</sup> As I wrote, you might develop a small thing that will alter this behavior for you, but it doesn't seem to be possible just with GitHub.